# How to Backup/Restore in PostgreSQL pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, restore, pgadmin

So I feel like this is something that should be very basic and easy to do, maybe I'm just not doing things correctly.

I want to do the equivalent of SQL Server backups. I want to create the equivalent of a full .bak file and be able to restore a database to its original state.

So far I've tried many different ways in PgAdmin4 to create a backup file from a freshly created database. I migrate my schema which creates a bunch of tables, then perform a restore on the previously created file. What I expect after the restore is for all those tables I created to be gone, I expect the database to be in the exact state that it was when I took the backup.

I've tried many different options like including the Create/Drop Database commands preserving/not saving data on backup/restore but have had no luck.

Anyone able to help me out here?

I am using commands `pg_dump mydb -Fc > db` and `pg_restore db`. Maybe there's some magic parameters I'm missing for it to do what I'm asking above?

Tried `pg_restore --clean db`, same results.

The problem is I create my database, fresh with nothing in it, take a backup of it, create some tables, restore the backup, and the tables I created are still there. I want a restore method that puts the db in the same state as it was when it was backed up.

Answer (score 3):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

As a workaround, forget pgAdmin, just run `pg_dump` from the command line.

See [25.1. SQL Dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html) in the Backup and Restore documentation.

Also from the [manual entry](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) for `pg_restore`:

> `-c`
>   `--clean`
>
> Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (Unless `--if-exists` is used, this might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

> `-C`
>   `--create`
>   Create the database before restoring into it. If `--clean` is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.
>
> When this option is used, the database named with `-d` is used only to issue the initial `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE` commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

...or simply manually drop the database before you restore it.

From [Why is pg_restore returning successfully but not actually restoring my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900888/why-is-pg-restore-returning-successfully-but-not-actually-restoring-my-database) on Stack Overflow, you also need to specify a `--dbname` when connecting, or it won't restore anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the [docs useful](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/backup_and_restore.html?highlight=restore)

It sounds to me like `pg_dump` is "The Backup Dialog" and `pg_dumpall` is "The Backup Server Dialog".

- [**The Backup Dialog**](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/backup_dialog.html)

  > **Using the `pg_dump` utility, pgAdmin provides an easy way to create a backup in a plain-text or archived format. You can then use a client application (like psql or the Query Tool) to restore a plain-text backup file, or use the Postgres `pg_restore` utility to restore an archived backup.** The `pg_dump` utility must have read access to all database objects that you want to back up.
- [**The Backup Server Dialog**](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/backup_server_dialog.html)

  > Use the Backup Server dialog to create a plain-text script that will recreate the selected server. You can use the pgAdmin Query Tool to play back a plain-text script, and recreate the server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `--clean` parameter that you found helpful in `pg_restore` translates to the "Clean before restore" option in the "Restore options" tab of the pgAdmin 4 restore dialog.

This option is necessary if you want the restore process to drop any existing tables/data before restoring your backup.

Comment: Sadly the Clean before restore does nothing.